# Why are concurrent requests disabled by default in AppEngine/Java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Much to my surprise I found out that AppEngine applications server requests serially. Recently Java applications have the possiblity to server requests concurrently , which is disabled by default ( [reference](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html#Using_Concurrent_Requests) ).

What is the reason for concurrent request being disabled by default? Web applications are by their nature meant to serve multiple requests concurrently, whether they are written in Java, Python or PHP. It seems to me like this is an artificial limitation.

Comment: Looks like I need to change my configuration. I didn't know of this.

Answer (score 6):

This may have something to do with AppEngine at the beginning not supporting concurrent requests.  The feature was only added for Java in version 1.4.3 (March 30, 2011).  So some developers may have coded and tested their applications to behave properly only against a single thread at a time.

Once Google built the infrastructure and code to support concurrent requests they may have been wary about enabling concurrency by default, as it could break existing applications.  Hence the reason for the opt in approach.

There are some GAE folk who check StackOverflow, so we might need to hear from them to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is the **better option by default** as many novice programmers are coding on appengine and expect minimalistic approach than scale/volume.

Concurrent PHP or python (process based) wont messup object data but Java can (thread based). That is the main difference.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As a Java web programmer, I should have a minimal knowledge of what is thread-safe and what is not. A servlet container like Tomcat or Jetty makes no effort to guard against it, and I still don't understand why appengine does.

Answer (score 1):

Probably to avoid regression for app already deployed and not thread safe ...

Answer (score 0):

In GAE doc, the "Note: If you wish to use concurrent requests, your application code needs to use proper thread synchronization before you enable ." is quite explicit about the danger of concurrent requesting.
As other people said above, this is less dangerous not to allow this feature by default and to provide it to advanced developers who go deeper in the documentation.
Yet, it is written quite small and at the end of the doc so it's not easy to see it :)

Comment: Well, I saw that. But given that threading is severely limited in GAE and that there is - IMO - no reason for GAE to be more complex in this respect that a 'run-of-the-mill' J2EE app, I still fail to see what the point is in disabling it by default.

Comment: The fact is that it's not quite a JEE app, it's just a facade looking like JDO or JPA but it's not in front of Hibernate+c3p0 which manage your connections in parallel (JDBC has a single-threaded design also...) Anyway, I don't know the exact reason for this in GAE, certainly some historical reasons).