# How to migrate to concurrent requests in Java App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, concurrency

In light of the new billing changes on App Engine, I saw that you can enable concurrent requests in Java App Engine. What specifically do you have to be careful of when enabling concurrent requests?

The docs say:

> By default, App Engine sends requests serially to a given web server.
>   You can configure App Engine to send multiple requests in parallel by
>   adding the <threadsafe> element to appengine-web.xml:
>   `<threadsafe>true</threadsafe>` 
> **Note:** If you wish to use concurrent
>   requests, your application code needs to use proper thread
>   synchronization before you enable <threadsafe>.

What exactly does this entail? I've developed against App Engine assuming requests are served in parallel by any number of machines. What actually changes when you assume concurrent requests on a single machine. I run no separate threads and have no global static variables. Is there anything else I need to worry about?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are concurrent requests disabled by default in AppEngine/Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385198/why-are-concurrent-requests-disabled-by-default-in-appengine-java)

Comment: Went through that thread, but the specific answer of check "mutable globals" was not listed there and was answered here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the element to appengine-web.xml is all that should be required. The only reason you'd have trouble is if you have mutable globals; these could be modified in parallel by multiple threads, so you need to protect them with concurrency primitives.

Comment: Great - no mutable globals so will enable. Thanks.